# Stack overflow reversal voting algorithm unfair

Tags: support, reputation, serial-voting

I joined stackoverflow 4 months ago and got really excited (addicted too) on solving other people's issues and editing first posts etc... Day before yesterday I hit the 1k reputation bar but was shocked a day after of reversal voting that brought me down to 700 after "serial votes were reversed".

I don't deny that two of my friends were up voting my answers but they did only up voted my accepted answers (I have roughly 15 accepted). They judged each answer, they choose to up vote or not. I didn't ask them to do it nor did I bribe them by any sort to do it. Actually, one friend once up voted one of my very average answer and we had argument about it because I simply believe it is wrong to do so and he took it down I believe.

Ethically, I wouldn't let anyone votes for me just for who I am. Also, I was a victim of a down voting multiple times just because my answer got accepted and another person' answer did not and that was never recovered.

Is there anyone who please can explain how reversal algorithm works? And is there a chance I get back my reputation points that were earned only on accepted answers?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Whether or not you were personally involved in the improper voting simply does not matter. All that matters is that improper votes were cast, and that they needed to be invdalidated. Regardless of how good your intentions were or whether you contribute positively otherwise, improper votes are improper votes and will be reversed.

Our "algorithm" that detects it automatically is incredibly forgiving and only reverses on extremely obvious cases. Frankly if your votes got struck by the automatic system, there is zero room for arguing about it because it would have been so blatantly obvious that there's no point in trying.

In your case, the votes were manually reversed by staff. We get reports of suspicious votes in several different ways which require us to look into the voting patterns more thoroughly and make a determination of whether the votes were cast in bad faith or not. This is actually still a very forgiving process that isn't open to debate once votes have been reversed. If votes were reversed manually, it was because we found strong evidence of improper voting in your recent history. There is no chance the votes will be restored or that you'll get the reputation back.

We have a few different things that we look for when determining whether votes were improper. One obvious one is a bunch of votes that came in seconds apart in a long string. We can't go into much detail about the specifics of voting irregularities, though, because it would just make it easier for people to get around our checks.

You and your friends should be more careful and make sure you actually are voting on post content and not just supporting each other. Quite frankly, having a third of your reputation come from your friends is very excessive and is detrimental to the reputation system overall. At a certain point, your reputation no longer represents how much the community trusts you, but rather how much your friends trust you. The 700 you are at now is a much more accurate reflection of that.

Comment: Fair enough, this was really helpful. Thank you so much.